# Paint on copper pipe leaching into my water supply?

Tags: plumbing, water

It’s been months since this has been changed but I just thought about the fact that the pipe we connected to had been painted before.

Is this white paint leaching into our water?

Any way to tell?

[image]

Comment: assume that it is and remove it

Comment: @jsotola - all the Paint?

Comment: the pipe should have been cleaned of paint to ensure a good seal anyway.

Comment: Since you can see paint under the sleeve where the quick connect is, one would assume the pipe is not properly cleaned (even though it is not leaking). So best bet would be redo the connection but clean the area to be fitted before reassembly. You'll need new insert-bushing for the connection to the valve. If you do this, you'll have peace of mind.

Comment: So just remove it and scrape off the paint to the point where quick connect reaches and that should be good enough?

Comment: The water flows on the inside of the pipe

Comment: Yes Ryan, light sand paper, and clean it with alcohol for example would remove any chance paint is touching water. To @Kris, while water is inside the pipe on the left, water also flows in any area exposed or accessible, and the pipe (fitting) on the right has a larger ID (Inner Diameter) than the pipe on the left with the paint. So there is basically (at a minimum) a presumable unseen lip (or slightly more) of paint inside the water jacket.

Comment: @Ryan, `all the Paint?` ... just at the connection ... paint cannot possibly go through the copper pipe walls ... after all, water does not come out any pores in the pipe

Comment: Keep in mind that the pipe was not painted prior to installation.  Somebody chose to paint it after it was installed.  So there is no paint on the inside or inside connectors.  What's on the outside can't get to the inside.

Comment: Is there any credible reason to believe the paint is actually leaden? It would have to be at least 40 years old.  Does it look 40?  Because it looks like a dead on match for the paint on the wall (matching dead-on isn't easy) so it was surely painted at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The Water is inside the pipe. The fitting you have on the left side connected to the painted pipe should be making a tight leak proof seal there should not be any paint at the point of inner seal. If you are concerned - remove the connection and sand the paint clean it and remove it then reconnect your fitting.

If the paint is lead based - you can try a lead test. Be forewarned that what is coming from your utility will probably be more than what you have from that paint area if anything at all.

Paint is not leaching from the outside of the copper to the inside of the pipe either.

Just thought I would add this picture to help you - see the insert sleeve that fits on the inside of the pipe - the white nylon piece. This seals the inside from the outside.

[image: Shark Bite Fitting]

Comment: Thanks Ken. Makes me feel better. I was just thinking that part of the painted pipe slides into the shark bite, so the outside becomes part of the inside.

Comment: @Ryan updated my answer with a picture to illustrate that you have nothing to be concerned about..